How to update a SP list item using Graph API in Postman where the actual item will be filtered based on Title field instead of ID
I am trying to update a SP list item using Graph API using Postman. I am Patching through below API.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{PO_ProdSite_ID}}/lists/0d9de749-9852-433c-9dgd-2242c02a9499/items?$expand=fields&$filter=fields/Number eq 'ABC00001234'
Body portion contains below.
{"fields":{"FieldToUpdate": "NewValue234567"}}
If I try to replace ?$expand=fields&$filter=fields/Number eq 'ABC00001234' with /ActualItemID, then the patch is working fine.
Otherwise, it gives "Invalid request" error.
I don't want to use item id value as filter here.
Please help me in this situation on how to solve this.
Thanks in advance!
